# find all element by class and clone them with different value

Tags: jquery, clone

i'm trying to create my first chrome extension. basically i want to search all links with a class name "child" in current loaded document. i need to retrieve the href value of each links. then i want to clone it into another class named "child_two". On the newly cloned element, the href will be replaced with a modified one.

This is the the target document.

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example1.com" class="child">name1</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example2.com" class="child">name2</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example3.com" class="child">name3</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example4.com" class="child">name4</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example5.com" class="child">name5</a>
</div>
```

I want the result to be like this.

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example1.com" class="child">name1</a>
    <a href="preview.php?link=http://www.example1.com" class="child_two">preview</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example2.com" class="child">name2</a>
    <a href="preview.php?link=http://www.example2.com" class="child_two">preview</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example3.com" class="child">name3</a>
    <a href="preview.php?link=http://www.example3.com" class="child_two">preview</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example4.com" class="child">name4</a>
    <a href="preview.php?link=http://www.example4.com" class="child_two">preview</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example5.com" class="child">name5</a>
    <a href="preview.php?link=http://www.example5.com" class="child_two">preview</a>
</div>
```

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.child").each(function (index, elem) { 
    $(elem).clone()
        .attr("href", "preview.php?link=" + $(elem).attr("href")).attr("class", "child_two").text("preview").appendTo($(elem).parent());
});​
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but i tried your codes and it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/9BHg5/

Comment: Corrected issue, also I noticed it wasn't including the jquery framework on that jsfiddle page, check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using after()'s function

```
$('.parent a.child').after(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return $el.clone().attr({
        'href': 'preview.php?link=' + $el.attr('href'),
        'class': 'child_two'
    }).text('preview');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3MFEu/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.child").each(function(){
    var newLink = $(this).clone();
    $(newLink).attr("href", "preview.php?link=" + $(this).attr("href"));
    $(newLink).attr("class", "child_two");
    $(newLink).text("Preview");
    $(newLink).insertAfter(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkU4r/2/

Updated - I failed to notice you want the second link to read "preview"